# Is it possible to create a bar chart where Y is the count of distinct values of a column in a Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

For example, if my table is something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ['abc', 'abc', 'def'],
                   'product': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']})
```

How can I return a bar chart where the dimension X is product and the metric y is the count of the distinct values of user_id?

Comment: The simplest way is to use `seaborn.countplot`: `sns.countplot(data=df, x='product', hue='user_id', dodge=False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `groupby` "product", count the unique values of "user_id" and plot:

```
(df.groupby('product')
   ['user_id'].nunique()
   .plot.bar()
)
```

output:

[image: stacked bar plot]

I find it a better example the other way around:

```
(df.groupby('user_id')
   ['product'].nunique()
   .plot.bar()
)
```

[image: bar plot]

You might also be interested in identifying the groups (again reversed example as more demonstrative):

```
(df.groupby('user_id')
   ['product'].value_counts()
   .unstack()
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

[image: stacked bar plot]